# Showing div only when current time is more than startDate and less than endDate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a div only when its time is bigger than `startDate` and less than `endDate`. For `startDate` and `endDate` itself I got from api data that i have, the format is like the variable below. I've made the code as below, even though the day is more than `startDate` but why the div doesn't appear? Is it because the time format is different?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let today = new Date()
  let startDate = "2021-12-13T00:00+07:00"
  let endDate = "2021-12-16T00:00+07:00"
  
  console.log(today)
  
  if(today > startDate && today < endDate){
    console.log('true')
    $('.date').css('display', 'block')
  }else{
    console.log('false')
  }
})
```

```css
.date{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="date">Date is bigger than startDate and less than endDate</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let today = new Date()
  let startDate = new Date("2021-12-13T00:00+07:00")
  let endDate = new Date("2021-12-16T00:00+07:00")
  
  console.log(today)
  
  if(today > startDate && today < endDate){
    console.log('true')
    $('.date').css('display', 'block')
  }else{
    console.log('false')
  }
})
```

```css
.date{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="date">Date is bigger than startDate and less than endDate</div>
```